# Getting the First Not Null Value with Group

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table

[image: Source Table]

Following is the result I am trying to achieve

[image: Result Set]

**Explanation**

I want to group the data by location and get the fist not null value that is available in the column. For example for **locationcd** 1300 the column **A** will have the value John, column **B** will have the value John, column **C** will have the value Taylor and column **D** will have the Value Brian.

**My Solution**

I did something which doesn't guarantee the correct result. Here is my query

```
select locationCd,
min([$1-$500]),
min([$501-$2500]) as '$501-$2500',
Min([$2501-$5000]) as '$2501-$5000',
min([$$5000 and above])  as '$$5000 and above'
from #tab
group by LocationCd
```

Please help.

Comment: please provide valid data it will help you to get better answer

Comment: First? Now a battle is coming with questions like which column determines the order. From your data it can be simply filtered with all columns `not null`

Comment: The result doesn't match the business rules?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Just What I needed. Thanks. Got an Idea, I'll post the solution here.

Comment: @Tanner Simple. Try and execute.

Comment: @P.Salmon Oops! My bad. Now corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query will give the required result :-

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( partition by locationCd order by locationCd) RID,locationCd,A,B,C,D into #t1 from table_name

select locationcd,min(A) A,
(select B from #t1 b where b.locationcd=a.locationcd AND b.RID=3) B,
(select C from #t1 c where c.locationcd=a.locationcd AND c.RID=2) C,
(select D from #t1 d where d.locationcd=a.locationcd AND d.RID=1) D
from #t1 a
group by locationcd

drop table #t1
```

Output :-

```
 locationcd   A       B      C      D
 200        David   David  Detlef  Brian
 201        David   David  Detlef  Brian
 400        Walter  Brad   Detlef  Brian
 1200       David   David  Detlef  Brian
 1300       John    John   Taylor  Brian
 1400       Walter  Brad   Detlef  Brian
```

Replace table_name by required table

Answer (score 0):

```
Select LocationId, MAX(Ty1.A) A
From #tabl T01
Outer Apply (Select Top 1 A From #tabl T1 Where T1.LocationId=T01.LocationId And T1.A Is Not Null) Ty1
Group By LocationId
```

does this help you ???

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as
 (select distinct locid from @t)
 select cte.locid, 
     (select top 1 cola from @t t where t.locid = cte.locid AND t.cola is not null) cola ,
      (select top 1 colb from @t t where t.locid = cte.locid AND t.colb is not null) colb, 
       (select top 1 colc from @t t where t.locid = cte.locid AND t.colc is not null) colc, 
        (select top 1 cold from @t t where t.locid = cte.locid AND t.cold is not null) cold 
 from   cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,. Hope this helps you...

```
select LocationCD,min(A),min(B),min(C),min(D)
from #tab
group by LocationCD
```